# How can I make my line thinner for a 3d Plot (setting linewidths lower than 1.5 seemd to have no effect)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot the path of a particle. I have numpy arrays of x,y and z- values. However I what the final line to be thinner yet lowering linewidths did not seem to yield an effect.

```
import numpy as np
import math

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

def euler(x_0, y_0, z_0, n, t_2):
    xs = [x_0]
    zs = [z_0]
    ys = [y_0]

    h= (t_2)/n

    for i in range(0,n):
        xs.append( xs[i] + 10*(ys[i] - xs[i])*h )
        ys.append( ys[i] + xs[i] * (28-zs[i])*h )
        zs.append( zs[i] + (xs[i]*ys[i] - 8*zs[i]/3)*h )

    return np.array([np.array(xs), np.array(ys), np.array(zs)])

result = euler(1,1,1, 5000, 5)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

ax.scatter(result[0], result[1], result[2], linewidths=[0])
plt.show()
```

Comment: What about changing `s`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the parameter 's':

```
ax.scatter(result[0], result[1], result[2], linewidth=1, s=1)
```